# having problem in displaying doubly circular linked list in python

Tags: python, data-structures, linked-list

I am currently learning data structures in python and I am having problem in `display()`
method in `CircularDoublyLinkedList` class

The while loop run infinitely by repeating the elements of the `CircularDoublyLinkedList` class

```
#my code:
class Node:
    def __init__(self,value):
        self.value=value
        self.next=None
        self.prev=None

class CircularDoublyLinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head=None
        self.tail=None

    def display(self):
        if self.head is None:
            return 'Circular doubly Linked list doesn\'t exists'
        else:
            node=self.head
            elements=[]
            while node:
                if node==self.tail:
                    break
                elements.append(node.value)
                print(node.value)
                node=node.next
        return elements

    def insertnode(self,value,position):
        node=Node(value)
        if self.head is None:
            self.head=node
            self.tail=node
            self.prev=node
            self.next=node
        else:
            if position==0:
                node.prev=self.tail
                node.next=self.head
                self.head=node
                self.head.prev=node
                self.tail.next=node
            elif position==-1:
                node.next=self.head
                node.prev=self.tail
                self.tail=node
                self.tail.next=node
                self.head.prev=node
            else:
                index=0
                tempnode=self.head
                while index<position-1:
                    tempnode=tempnode.next
                    index+=1
                node.next=tempnode.next
                node.prev=tempnode
                node.next.prev=node
                tempnode.next=node

#creating objects

cdll=CircularDoublyLinkedList()
cdll.insertnode(5,0)
cdll.insertnode(0,0)
cdll.insertnode(1,-1)
cdll.insertnode(2,2)

print(cdll.display())
```

I tried changing the `if` condition inside `display()` method from `node==self.tail` to `node==self.tail.next` but nothing changed

So how to resolve this error in `display()` method of class `CircularDoublyLinkedList`?

any help will be appreciated...thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues:

- In `display`, the `break` should come *after* you have printed the `tail` value. So that loop should look like this:

  ```
  while node:
      elements.append(node.value)
      print(node.value)
      if node==self.tail:
          break
      node=node.next
  ```
- In `insertnode`, for the first case, you are assigning to `self.prev` and `self.next`, but those are not attributes that belong to `self` (which is a linked list instance, not a node instance). Instead you want:

  ```
  node.prev=node
  node.next=node
  ```
- In `insertnode`, for the second case, you should not change `self.head` before assigning to `self.head.prev`. So swap these statements so you get this order:

  ```
  self.head.prev=node
  self.head=node
  ```
- In `insertnode`, for the remaining case, you have a similar issue as in the previous point: first assign to `self.tail.next` and only then move the `self.tail` reference, so you get this order of execution:

  ```
  self.tail.next=node
  self.tail=node
  ```

With those fixes your code will work as expected.

### Other remarks and alternative

In a circular doubly linked list you don't need a tail reference, because in a non-empty list that `self.tail` is *always* going to be equal to `self.head.prev`. So there is really no good reason to maintain it in a separate attribute. Leaving it out makes the code shorter without losing on efficiency.

As no node in a circular doubly linked list has a `None` value for either `prev` or `next`, it is more natural to initialise these attributes with a self-reference in the `Node` constructor.

Printing inside a method is not really nice: it mixes the linked-list logic with I/O concerns. Instead, make the linked list iterable by implementing the `__iter__` method, and keep the printing in the main program code.

The code for `insertnode` can be reduced, by only determining what `node.next` must be, and then all the rest of the "wiring" can be common to all cases. The only exception is when a node is added to an empty list.

Applying those points we get this:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.next = self.prev = self  # No None in a doubly linked list

class CircularDoublyLinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None  # No tail needed

    def __iter__(self):  # iterator is useful for many scenarios
        node = self.head
        if node:
            yield node.value
            while node.next != self.head:
                node = node.next
                yield node.value

    def insertnode(self, value, position):
        node = Node(value)
        if not self.head:
            self.head = node  # node is already correctly wired
            return
        node.next = self.head
        if position == 0:
            self.head = node
        while position > 0:  # No need for an index variable
            node.next = node.next.next
            position -= 1
        # Common code:
        node.prev = node.next.prev
        node.prev.next = node.next.prev = node

cdll = CircularDoublyLinkedList()
cdll.insertnode(5, 0)
cdll.insertnode(0, 0)
cdll.insertnode(1, -1)
cdll.insertnode(2, 2)

print(*cdll)  # Use iterator for displaying
```

Comment: Thank you sir for your detailed explaination... ***:)***

Comment: Sir it's giving me an error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'next'` in line 32 i.e `node.prev.next = node.next.prev = node` and in line 36 `cdll.insertnode(0, 0)`

Comment: You must have done something different then. See it run on [repl.it](https://replit.com/@trincottrincots/httpsstackoverflowcoma695156395459839)

Comment: oh..yes sir got it...thanks again sir **:)**

Comment: Hello sir,can you help me out on this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70423790/my-custom-heapify-method-not-working-properly-in-python?noredirect=1#comment124488086_70423790 thanks

Answer (score 1):

The loop inside `display()` must stop when the next node is the **head** of the list:

```
    def display(self):
        if self.head is None:
            return 'Circular doubly Linked list doesn\'t exists'
        else:
            node=self.head
            elements=[]
            while node:
                elements.append(node.value)
                print(node.value)
                node=node.next
                if node==self.head: break
        return elements
```

Review the method `insertnode()` to make sure it is correct! I think it is not working properly.